# Появляется «дополнительная страница безопасности» при авторизации Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, безопасность

Добрый день!

Есть кейс:

Сайт на Wordpress
При попытке входа на страницу авторизации в админку site.com/wp-admin под анонимным пользователем в браузере или с другого ip, или после чистки кэша редиректит сначала на эту страницу
http://joxi.ru/MAjdDBMHvONK3m
после решения примера - редирект на нужную страницу.

Это же происходит при ajax запросе постов (возвращается 200-ая с версткой такой вот "страницы безопасности").

Вопрос: что это такое и могу ли я как-то это отключить/убрать/управлять?

Решено
Спасибо за помощь! 
Оказалось, что это доп. функционал хостинга - "Дополнительная защита CMS". Отключил ее на в админке самого хостинга

Answer (score 0):

Это не WordPress, такого функционала в ядре нет. Отключите все плагины поочередно, найдете где "безопасность" зарыта. И выкиньте этот плагин сразу и навсегда. Для безопасности есть [Wordfence](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) плагин.